# PHP file in module which can handle get requests from outside

Tags: php, get, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to create module that will be able to handle get requests from outside. I would like to have a separate php file for get requests, also I would like to be able to use prestashop function and classes in this file. How to do that? I assume that I have to import something into this file, but what?

I'm green as it goes for prestashop module development so please don't be harsh.

Comment: "from outside" of what? I suggest you do some tutorials on PHP programming and learn how the web functions...

Comment: From outside prestashop environment, another domain let's say. Sorry I thought it was obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found it :)
When you import config.inc.php into your file, you can use prestashop functions etc.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).